# Fedora 12 Wireless problems (Intel Wireless 4965AGN Card)

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, fedora

I'm having an interesting experience with my wireless card at the moment. Basically, it goes like this:

- I connect to the local wireless network (netgear router)
- It works, briefly, allowing me to browse a webpage or maybe two, if I'm lucky.
- It then stops working / sending any packets, whilst reported still connected.

Now, me  being me I've had a look to see what I can find. wpa_supplicant.log looks like this:

```
Trying to associate with valid_mac:a2:30 (SSID='vennardwireless' freq=2462 MHz)
Associated with valid_mac:a2:30
WPA: Key negotiation completed with valid_mac:a2:30 [PTK=CCMP GTK=TKIP]
CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to valid_mac:a2:30 completed (reauth) [id=0 id_str=]
CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED - Disconnect event - remove keys
```

So that's working fine. `dmesg | grep "*iwl*"` spits out this:

```
iwlagn: Intel(R) Wireless WiFi Link AGN driver for Linux, 1.3.27kds
iwlagn: Copyright(c) 2003-2009 Intel Corporation
iwlagn 0000:03:00.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 17 (level, low) -> IRQ 17
iwlagn 0000:03:00.0: setting latency timer to 64
iwlagn 0000:03:00.0: Detected Intel Wireless WiFi Link 4965AGN REV=0x4
iwlagn 0000:03:00.0: Tunable channels: 13 802.11bg, 19 802.11a channels
iwlagn 0000:03:00.0: irq 32 for MSI/MSI-X
phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-agn-rs'
iwlagn 0000:03:00.0: firmware: requesting iwlwifi-4965-2.ucode
iwlagn 0000:03:00.0: loaded firmware version 228.61.2.24
Registered led device: iwl-phy0::radio
Registered led device: iwl-phy0::assoc
Registered led device: iwl-phy0::RX
Registered led device: iwl-phy0::TX
iwlagn 0000:03:00.0: iwl_tx_agg_start on ra = 00:24:b2:32:a3:30 tid = 0
iwlagn 0000:03:00.0: iwl_tx_agg_start on ra = 00:24:b2:32:a3:30 tid = 0
```

So that's working too. I can also `ping 192.168.0.1 -I wlan0` and `arping 192.168.0.1 -I wlan0` the router until the network falls over.

`uname -r`:`2.6.32.10-90.fc12.x86_64`. Laptop is a Core2 Duo (2Ghz) with 3GB RAM. Other symptoms I've noticed are that wireshark freezes when I capture on the "broken" interface until I disconnect. Am using networkmanager as per normal. Stupidly, I can connect to the same router via eth0/a cat6 cable just fine. Everyone else can connect to the AP fine (from Windows). Yes, I'm sat right next to it and not trying to access a hotspot the other side of the world.

Any ideas? Is this a broken update? (I intend to reboot and test an older kernel later)? Anyone else come across this?

Edit: `iwconfig wlan0 rate auto` is the settings I'm using for rates. Also, **according to networkmanager the network is still connected.**

Thanks for any pointers / advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the same problem. I can use the wireless connection about 3 sec, after that it brokes.
I have tried a newer kernel from testing and it is 2.6.32.10-92 and the problem still exists.

Now i can't even connect to the network over the wlan (n-draft, WPA2).

I found a post which also descripe the problem

http://fedoraforum.org/forum/showthread.php?p=1347950

Comment: Thanks, there's a link to a bugzilla on there too with a fixed kernel (-94). I thought it was a kernel bug. Thanks for confirming.